Using GU50s in a guitar amp
I have a number of GU50s from Ukraine - they were a soviet copy of the German LS50 and are apparently seen as a good tube on the HiFi side of things. The datasheets are easy to find but the ones I can find are a little limited. I have two related questions:

The LS50 datasheet suggests they work with a positive grid 1 voltage of up to 20v. Basic tube physics suggests that this ought to cause problems with grid 1 current, although I could imagine a scenario where a sparsely wound grid 1 could further accelerate electrons without capturing too many for this to work - is it really ok to drive these with a positive grid voltage and, if so, does the circuit need any special arrangements in the grid circuits (other than an extra 20v of drive to get maximum output)?

The GU50 datasheet only shows anode curves for a maximum grid 1 voltage of 0v - I am assuming the answer is "yes" (because the construction looks identical) but is the GU50 also capable of operating with positive grid voltages?


These tubes have a number of potential advantages: As they can dissipate up to 40W, you ought to be able to get 60W output from a single pair reasonably easily (although some attention might also be needed with regard to screen dissipation). They are also comparatively cheap!

In tetrodes and pentodes, Vg1 and Vg2 can be traded off against each other, in proportion of amplification factor (μg2g1).
The main reason you would want positive Vg1 (class 2 operation), is because an application requires more Ia peak than is available at rated Vg2, and when this does not violate other limits, like power.  Class C, ICAS, or especially pulsed service, are examples.  Class AB, CCS, not so much.
For a class AB amplifier, using a type having ample Ia at nominal Vg2, positive grid drive isn't very useful, and RC coupled grid drive and class AB1 operation is perfectly acceptable.
The operating range is ballpark similar to 6L6GC, 6550 or KT88; I would suggest following circuits based on those, adjusting supply voltage, bias current and load impedance to suit (look up load line analysis for more detail).  The main difference, being a true pentode, the plate saturation curve is much softer, leading to higher Va(min) and Ig2, which cost some efficiency and power range versus a beam tetrode.  You may prefer a relatively high B+ and RL for this reason.

I've been using the load line calculator here: https://www.vtadiy.com/loadline-calculators/loadline-calculator/ I've set a B+ of 480V, a bias of 70mA and a load of 7k. With Vg2 at the nominal 250V then AB1 is perfectly respectable but lowering Vg2 to 150V gets you a tiny bit of extra headroom (although much harder to drive) - but I can see that you could do the same more easily by raising the B+. I need to do some more reading about AB2 but I am curious as to whether you could still use RC coupled grid drive or would need a different approach to provide sufficient current into grid 1?

Grid current is dropped by the bias resistor, so you need lower and lower values as Ig1(av) goes up, or stronger decoupling (e.g. gate drive transformer), or a more active solution like a cathode follower. The nonlinear load also increases distortion.
